# How to invoke a method which returns an interface

Tags: c#, reflection, types, interface, idatareader

I am invoking a method on a type via reflection which takes a couple of parameters:

```
var myType = typeof(myClass);

var myMethod = myType.GetMethod("myMethodInClass", 
                                 new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });

myMethod.Invoke(?, new object[] { "", "" });
```

I want the target to be an IDataReader, which is what the method will return, but I obviously cannot instantiate a new instance of an interface.

Comment: Just pass an object and cast it afterwards.

Comment: normally cast the return value to your interface, like `(IYourInterface) myMethod.Invoke...`

Comment: As everyone is saying, you should create an object that implements the interface, then cast it. You might want to look into [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/). Dependency injection might be just what you need

Comment: Why not `var result = (IDataReader)myMethod.Invoke(new myClass(), new object[] { "", "" });`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have put `?` in the the question should not be `IDataReader`, but an instance of `myClass`. You are passing in the object on which you want to invoke `myMethod`.

The result from calling `.Invoke()` will be an `IDataReader`, but that is not something you are creating; it is created inside the method you are invoking.

Comment: `the same instance you used above` no, `myType` is an object describing type, which is of type `Type` and `myClass` is a type name. `typeof` can't be used with a variable name

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return interface, but you can return an instance of class which implement the interface your method returns. Just cast it.

```
IDataReader implemented = new YourClass(); // or any other constructor
```

Your class must only implement IDataReader interface. You can insert your class instance in the place of `?` and `implemented` might be result of `myMethod.Invoke(yourClassInstance, new object[] { "", "" })`.

Answer (score 2):

```
myMethod.Invoke(?, new object[] { "", "" });
```

? has nothing with returning interface, but it's the actual object of which's method you are calling. If you know that this method returns class which implements `IDataReader` just write

```
IDataReader rd=myMethod.Invoke(yourInstance, new object[] { "", "" });.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return interface type instance .but you can explicitly cast into interface type and can solve this out.

```
((myMethod.Invoke . . . ) as InterfaceType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the way you think you would:

```
class Gadget
{
  public IList<int> FizzBuzz( int length , int startValue )
  {
    if ( length < 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length") ;
    int[] list = new int[length];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.Length ; ++i )
    {
      list[i] = startValue++ ;
    }
    return list ;
  }
}
class Program
{
  static void Main( string[] args )
  {
    object     x             = new Gadget() ;
    Type       t             = x.GetType() ;
    MethodInfo mi            = t.GetMethod("FizzBuzz") ;
    object     returnedValue = mi.Invoke( x , new object[]{ 10 , 101 } ) ;
    IList<int> returnedList  = (IList<int>) returnedValue ;
    string     msg           = returnedList.Select( n => n.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Aggregate( (s,v) => string.Format("{0}...{1}" , s , v) ) ;
    Console.WriteLine(msg) ;
    return;
  }
}
```